# parent grid rowindex from child grid button click ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I gave a nested grid. while clicking on a button in child grid I have to get parent grid row index. I have used like this type of code

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "go")

          {

        GridViewRow Gv2Row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        GridView Childgrid = (GridView)(Gv2Row.Parent.Parent);

        GridViewRow Gv1Row = (GridViewRow)(Childgrid.NamingContainer);
        GridView Parentgrid = (GridView)(Gv1Row.Parent.Parent);
        }
}
```

but it's not working..
Showing typecasting error . How to solve that..

Comment: Can you please error detail and error line numner?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "go")
    {
        GridViewRow Gv2Row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
        GridView Childgrid = (GridView)(Gv2Row.Parent.Parent);
        GridViewRow Gv1Row = (GridViewRow)(Childgrid.NamingContainer);
        int b = Gv1Row.RowIndex;
        // Access your parent grid index here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your solution, it may be helpfull to someone else ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an extra `(` and `)` for the code in commented line below resulting in `typecasting` error. And you don't need the last statement in your code because you have already found the parent grid.

I would suggest you better change the naming convention for the `parent/child gridview/row` object in your code to make it understand better as detailed below.

```
if (e.CommandName == "go")
{
   // GridViewRow Gv2Row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
   GridViewRow childrow = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
   GridView parentgrid = (GridView)(childrow.Parent.Parent);
   GridViewRow parentrow = (GridViewRow)(parentgrid.NamingContainer);
   int parentrowindex = parentrow.RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: If it helped you solve the problem then mark it as answer by checking the little `right tick mark` available at the left side of the answer. It will help the future visitors to this thread.